# Cannot find Auto activation triggers for Java

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

I am using an eclipse with this Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0), but when i go to content assist in order to enable autocomplete with `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ._` this form, i cannot seem to find Auto activation triggers for Java, just Auto activation triggers which does not allow more than 4 characters. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You **probably** tried to change the **same named preference for Ant** (where in fact only four characters are allowed) **instead of** changing the **preference for Java** (where there is no four character limit):

*Window > Preferences: **Java** > Editor > Content Assist*

Make sure, also enable *Disable insertion triggers except 'Enter'* (for details see [Eclipse 4.10 - New and Noteworthy](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.10/jdt.php#ignore-completion-proposal-insertion-triggers) or [watch this video](https://youtu.be/aM3UUycl1rs?t=209)).